# Is my solution of this differential equation correct?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We have

$y' = y \cdot \cos(x)$ without an initial value problem

My attempt:

We have $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g(y) = y$

$F(x) = \int f(x) dx = \int \cos(x) dx = \sin(x) + c_1$
$G(y) = \int \frac{1}{g(y)} dy= \ln(|y|) + c_2$

$G^{-1}(z) = e^z + c$
$=> y = \phi(x) = G^{-1}(F(x)) = e^{\sin(x)}+c$

But some online calculator tell me that it's: $y=c \cdot e^{\sin(x)}$
I don't see why.

Comment: You can write it as $$\Large e^{\sin x + c} = e^c e^{\sin x} = c e^{\sin x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically useless as an answer, but I'll write here anyway: your solution is correct!

Well done.